# How can I write an XSD which doesn't care what the root element is called?

Tags: xsd

My XML files have restrictions on the child elements, but it really doesn't matter what the name of the root element is.  How can I incorporate this into my XSD?  I've tried using `<xs:any>` but I get:

"S4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The Content Of 'schema' Is Invalid. Element 'any' Is Invalid, Misplaced, Or Occurs Too Often."

So I tried missing the name off the element tag like this: `<xs:element>` but then I get:

"S4s-att-must-appear: Attribute 'name' Must Appear In Element 'element'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I might just make the requirement stricter and insist on using a particular tag as the root element.  The fact that the application doesn't care is not really a problem.

It seems (to me) strange that this limitation exists, but I am new to XSDs.

Comment: What "limitation" do you mean?

Comment: The limitation that you must specify the name of the root attribute.

Comment: I think you mean root element.  If so, then you appear to be laboring under a misapprehension.  Not only do you not have to specify the name of the root element in an XSD schema, you *cannot* specify the name of the root element:  XSD has no construct for constraining the name of the document's root element.  This is a design characteristic of XSD that many have complained about.  As has already been explained, the named types of XSD offer direct support for the scenario you describe.  The "limitation" is a figment of your imagination.

Comment: Thanks for the further clarification, I understand your explanation now.  However, I am not sure what will be used for validation and so I was looking for a solution which starts the validation at the top of the document (which is presumably the default), and which does not specify the name of the first element.  The fact that this is not possible is the limitation.  However, I have given my workaround above.

Comment: You really need to start reading the answers people give to your questions.  Where validation starts, and whether it starts with an element declaration or a type definition or with a search for an appropriate element declaration is (as has already been explained here) determined by the validator's API or UI, not by XSD (which is not in the business of specifying either APIs or UIs).  You have already been told how to achieve your scenario; if you really insist on not achieving it, the limitation is pretty clearly yours and not XSD's.

Comment: I have read your responses and the matter is now resolved; I have produced my XSD. The consumers of my XSD have two options.  
1. Use it with what is presumably the default option, i.e. their validator checks all the XML starting with the root element. Then they  have to have a root element with a name conforming to the one in the schema. This restriction is not necessary for our application, but it would do no harm.
2. They can edit the XSD and remove the element which corresponds to the root element in their XML file, and tell their validator to start on the child elements.  Its up to them.

Answer (score 1):

Use a named type, and tell your validator to start validation at the root element using that type.

(There is one possible hitch with this:  XSD 1.0 suggests that as one possible invocation option, but does not require validators to provide it, so there's no guarantee the validator interface you use will support it.  Depends on your validator.  Worth trying, at least.)

Another way to put this:  you already have what you are asking for, because your XSD schema *never* cares what the root element of your document instance is called.  An XSD schema provides a set of element and type declarations (among other things).  A validator can be requested to start the validation at any point in the document, not just the root, and with either an element declaration or a type declaration, or in 'lax wildcard mode' (the most common default).  If your validator doesn't offer the invocation options you want, it's a flaw in your choice of validator, not a gap in XSD.

Comment: I am not sure how much control we have over the validator, so thanks for the suggestion but probably not a good option for our requirements.

Comment: You're invoking a validator but you have no control over how the validator is invoked?  I wonder how you got yourself in that kind of situation.